# Create a bootstrap grid column dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to generate a bootstrap grid with columns: calss = "col-lg-6" and "col-lg-3".
here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="../dist/images/test-info.png" alt="TEST-PLAN"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="../dist/images/test-details.png" alt="TEST-DETAILS"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="../dist/images/test-stats.png" alt="TEST-STATS"/>
</div></div></div>
```

However I would like to generate the above grid dynamically, in such a way that when `class ="col-lg-6"`, it should display the 'TEST-STATS' image with its correct position mentioned in the json below:

```
var data = [
    {
        "widgetId": "widget_0",
        "title": "Test Info",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
        "dataType": "TEST_INFO",
        "position": {
            "col": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "widgetId": "widget_1",
        "title": "Test Details",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
        "dataType": "TEST_DETAILS",
        "position": {
            "col": 2,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 2,
            "size_y": 4
        }
    },
    {

     "widgetId": "widget_2",
     "title": "Test Stats",
     "description": "",
     "type": "info",
    "dataType": "TEST_STATS",
    "position": {
            "col": 4,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 4
               }
}]
```

Every image has its own position to render, so a conditional statement like:

```
if(class=="col-lg-6")
{//display image as 'TEST-DETAILS'}
```

how to create a dynamic template and write a javascript function to loop for the classes and display the image according to the position?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of example on internet.

One of the best that I used is : http://www.cssgrid.co/

Very light and powerful to work with.

**EDIT**: since 2017, I'm using the CSS flex attributes. In my opinion, the CSS Grid frameworks are not really helpful those days.

Comment: The link is 404.

Comment: I'm not working with this anymore. Actually, using CSS with it's flex entities. But if you still need a great lib, you can use: http://www.cssgrid.co/ (updated my post with it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery class selector in order to select the element with class col-lg-6 and then set the attribute alt to TEST-DETAILS
ex. $(".col-lg-6").attr("alt", "TEST-DETAILS")